# how to set specific date only 15th and last day on datetimepicker php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, momentjs

I want to set the date or enable only the 15th and last of the month using the datetimepicker, there's something lacking with the script.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="adjustment_date" name="adjustment_date">
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#adjustment_date').datetimepicker({ 
       format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
       "defaultDate":new Date()  

});
</script>
```

Comment: you can use -> defaultDate: "11/1/2013",disabledDates: [moment("12/25/2013"),new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),"11/22/2013 00:53"]

Comment: i only want to get the 15th the last day on every month.

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates

Comment: you want to enable calendar dated from 1 to 15 on every month?

Comment: Not sure if that is dynamically possible using this specific component. It has a `daysOfWeekDisabled` option, but you would need the same thing rather for the month. Some other datepicker libraries allow you to specify a callback function that is called for each date shown in the calendar, that determines whether that particular date should be shown as enabled or disabled, but this one here only seems to allow to specify `en/disabledDates` with a static array of values. If you have a min and max date set anyway, you could create the array with all the necessary entries dynamically.

Comment: maybe could their someone who able to specify dates on this library.